# Integer to String Formatter issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, string-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I know this is very common question but I am really stuck in this matter.

I just want to covert Integer value to string using formatter.

Example like,
Suppose the integer value is like `1252` then It will convert into `1,252` and If like `1256256` then It will convert into `1,256,256`, It means to insert comma after every 3 digits..

Please help me to solve such a basic problem..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Convert integer to NSNumber and use NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1256256];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
NSString *finalString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `NSNumberFormatter` [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about `setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`.